# nDSM tree detection using scipy watershed

Tags: python, dem, classification, image-segmentation, scipy

I am trying to generate segments with single trees in a normalized surface model (nDSM). I tried using scipy.ndimage to achieve this, but the segmentation results are not precise. I would like a better segmentation. How could I achive this?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import rasterio

from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage.segmentation import watershed
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage import filters

src = rasterio.open('nDSM.tif')
img = src.read(1)

img = np.where(img > 5, img, 0)
img = ndi.gaussian_filter(img, sigma=0.5)
distance = ndi.distance_transform_edt(img)
coords = peak_local_max(distance, footprint=np.ones((2, 2)), labels=img)

mask = np.zeros(distance.shape, dtype=bool)
mask[tuple(coords.T)] = True

markers, _ = ndi.label(mask)
labels = watershed(img, markers, mask=mask)
```

[image]

Comment: I would recommend the lidR package in R for this.

Answer (score 1):

So after some research I came to the conclusion that the detection of the tree peaks (maxima) was not sufficient and therefore the segmentation did not work correctly.

Here is my updated Code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import rasterio

from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion, generate_binary_structure
from skimage.segmentation import watershed


def detect_peaks(image):

    neighborhood = generate_binary_structure(2,2)
    local_max = ndi.maximum_filter(image, footprint=neighborhood)==image
    background = (image==0)
    eroded_background = binary_erosion(background, structure=neighborhood, border_value=1)
    detected_peaks = local_max ^ eroded_background

    return detected_peaks

src = rasterio.open('nDSM.tif')
img = src.read(1)
img = ndi.gaussian_filter(img, sigma=0.5)


distance = img
mask  = detect_peaks(distance)

markers, _ = ndi.label(mask)
labels = watershed(-distance, markers, mask=img)
```

[image]